# Call a method from Activity on BroadcastReceiver called by an AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm new to asking, so I hope my question is correctly asked. Thanks in advance!

My problem is:

A `BroadcastReceiver` is called by an `AlarmManager` in this way by a method inside the same `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pi);
```

onRecieve works until I put there the method from `MainActivity`. When the call is on the code, i get this error every time the `AlarmManager` tries to start the onReceive:

```
12-22 21:56:01.020: W/BroadcastQueue(2192): Unable to launch app com.example/10000 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x14 cmp=com.example/.Receiver (has extras) }: process is bad
```

If I create a method on the `BroadcastReceiver` that recieves `MainActivity`, I can call methods from `MainActivity` inside that method of BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void SetHandler(Context context, MainActivity main) {
    MainActivity mainactivity;
this.mainactivity = main;
mainactivity.method();
}
```

But I can't understand how to call them inside the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver.

`mainactivity.method()` on the onRecieve doesn't work, I don't know if it is because it is not attached  to the `MainActivity` by the `AlarmManager` or if it is because I'm doing it wrong.

If the problem is because of the attachment of the activity with the BroadcastReceiver, how is it done?
If that's not the problem, what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` to activity and create an `IntentService` put it in `AlarmManager` and in `handleIntent` function of your service send a braodcast to the provided `IntentFilter` and you will be able to call Activity methods in `onReceive`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this `process is bad` error, and I had to keep my FCM Service exported.
add:

```
android:exported="true"
```

or remove **exported="false"** altogether.

My services now looks like this:

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Hopefully this helps you too.